# chardinjs is not working in ruby on rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

Hello I try [chardin js website](https://github.com/heelhook/chardin.js-rails) for my project.but some how it is not worked.I am working on rails 3.2.14 and ruby 1.9.3 and chardin js version is 0.1.3, so please help me. Here i attach fiddle link.

Edit: 
  Same things tried on my project(in view). but when i clicked on See it on action image is not appear.

Homes.coffee

```
$('body').chardinJs()

$('a[data-toggle="chardinjs"]').on 'click', (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    if $('.jumbotron img').is(':visible')
        ($('body').data('chardinJs')).toggle()
    else
        $('.jumbotron img').animate height: 250, 600, ->
            ($('body').data('chardinJs')).toggle()

$('body').on 'chardinJs:stop', ->
    $('a.btn.primary').off('click').text('See more on Github')
        .attr('href', 'https://github.com/heelhook/chardin.js')
    $('a#opentour').css display: 'block'
```

css same as in fiddle

homes/show.html.erb

```
  <body>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 data-intro="Project title" data-position="right">Chardin.js</h1>
  <p class="lead">
  Simple overlay instructions for your apps.
  </p>
  <img src="http://s11.postimg.org/5j9wr7n8z/chardin.png" data-intro="An awesome 18th-     century painter, who found beauty in everyday, common things." data-position="right" />
  <a id="asdfg" href="#" class="btn btn-large primary" data-toggle="chardinjs" data-intro="This button toggles the overlay, you can click it, even when the overlay is visible" data-position="left">See it in action</a>
  <a href="" id="opentour" class="hide" data-toggle="chardinjs">Or open it again</a>
  <div class="credits">
  <p data-intro="Author of this plugin, aka Pablo Fernandez" data-position="right">
    Baked with
    <b>&lt;3</b>
    by
    <a href="https://github.com/heelhook">@heelhook</a>.
  </p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="links">
  <p id="links" data-intro="Links to Github, Twitter, etc." data-position="top">
  </p>
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require chardinjs.min
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: your fiddle misses chardin.js, makes things difficult

Comment: i fixed that.add chardinjs.js as a external resources

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ABPrime/5ah1wsyz/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like your issue can be the same as your gist's: you think github is a CDN but its not.

For js, use `https://cdn.rawgit.com/heelhook/chardin.js/master/chardinjs.js`

For css, use `https://cdn.rawgit.com/heelhook/chardin.js/master/chardinjs.css`

Comment: yup you are right. now check my question what i exactly want.

Comment: Change this link: `.attr('href','https://github.com/heelhook/chardin.js')` try google.com for instance

Comment: thanks for reply . i tried google.com still image is not showing.

Comment: i put console.log after data-toggle on click event but console.log message is not work.

Comment: well... find a way to ilustrate in in your fiddle because: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s244/sh/2cbf0a1c-e872-4b69-b013-23c8833cf97d/985ca1c2058b287fda87aba35a90a43c

Answer (score 1):

Actually by mistake i put both files(`chardinjs.js and chardinjs.min.js`) in `assets/javascript`. And in `application.js` file require_tree load all tree js files. so that was a problem and also  changed `document.ready` in `homes.coffee` file.